# Get Elapsed Time as Human Friendly String

Tags: c#, datetime

In lieu with several other Facebook-esque concepts I am trying to replicate, this working code will take the span of time from a given date to now, and try to convert it into the most convenient English-friendly word. For example, if I post a comment on an article or status, and I want to show when it was posted to a user who views it, it would indicate something like "5 minutes ago", versus a date itself.

Concerns: Does this cover all possible use cases? Is it done optimally in the least lines of code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Schloss.Text
{
    public static class Date
    {
        public static string GetElapsedTime(DateTimeOffset datetime)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(datetime);

            int years = ts.Days / 365;
            int months = ts.Days / 30;
            int weeks = ts.Days / 52;

            if (years == 1) // one year ago
                return "A year ago";

            if (years > 1) // greater than one year
            {
                if (ts.Days % 365 == 0) // even year
                    return (int)(ts.TotalDays / 365) + " years ago";
                else // not really entire years
                    return "About " + (int)(ts.TotalDays / 365) + " years ago";
            }

            if (months == 1) // one month
                return "About a month ago";

            if (months > 1) // more than one month
                return "About " + months + " months ago";

            if (weeks == 1) // a week ago
                return "About a week ago";

            if (weeks > 1) // more than a week ago, but less than a month ago
                return "About " + weeks + " weeks ago";

            if (ts.Days == 1) // one day ago
                return "Yesterday";

            if (ts.Days > 1) //  more than one day ago, but less than one week ago
                return ts.Days + " days ago";

            if (ts.Hours == 1) // An hour ago
                return "About an hour ago";

            if (ts.Hours > 1 && ts.Hours <= 24) // More than an hour ago, but less than a day ago
                return "About " + ts.Hours + " hours ago";

            if (ts.Minutes == 1)
                return "About a minute ago";

            if (ts.Minutes == 0)
                return ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";

            return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen a dual system in use, where recent posts are "1 hour ago", "2 days ago" etc. but for earlier posts it switches to "20014-03-22" style date format you want.  I am not quite sure where the switch over is done, but I can't remember seeing "1 week ago" so it is probably less than that.

Comment: Not all years are 365 days, not all months are 30 days. [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1083991/648075) to "How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?" will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this cover all possible use cases?

Maybe, but it doesn't calculate timespan components (year, month, etc) exactly.

> Is it done optimally in the least lines of code?

Probably no.
You could generalize check of different `TimeSpan` elements using the following approach:

```
private static string GetElapsedTime(DateTime datetime)
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(datetime);

    // The trick: make variable contain date and time representing the desired timespan,
    // having +1 in each date component.
    DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue + ts;

    return ProcessPeriod(date.Year - 1, date.Month - 1, "year")
           ?? ProcessPeriod(date.Month - 1, date.Day - 1, "month")
           ?? ProcessPeriod(date.Day - 1, date.Hour, "day", "Yesterday")
           ?? ProcessPeriod(date.Hour, date.Minute, "hour")
           ?? ProcessPeriod(date.Minute, date.Second, "minute")
           ?? ProcessPeriod(date.Second, 0, "second")
           ?? "Right now";
}

private static string ProcessPeriod(int value, int subValue, string name, string singularName = null)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (value == 1)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(singularName))
        {
            return singularName;
        }
        string articleSuffix = name[0] == 'h' ? "n" : String.Empty;
        return subValue == 0
            ? String.Format("A{0} {1} ago", articleSuffix, name)
            : String.Format("About a{0} {1} ago", articleSuffix, name);
    }
    return subValue == 0
        ? String.Format("{0} {1}s ago", value, name)
        : String.Format("About {0} {1}s ago", value, name);
}
```

Comment: Is the removal of the "yesterday" case personal taste?

Comment: @TylerHarden No, I just not came up with how to generalize it, sorry.

Comment: @TylerHarden I've updated the answer. Now it should work not worse than yours. Please revise.